# How to query for Documents where the Fieldpath is always different

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an App where there are Documents for each car. I somehow need to query the Documents in a Collection to give me the ones where a User has worked on some Tasks.

The Problem is however, the Fieldpath in each Document is different so I cant query with a static Fieldpath.

Here is the Example Structure of an Document, and yes I know it is one of the worst ways to do it but I already made it a long time ago.

[image]

So what would be the best way to get the `worker` Array Queried if the FieldPath is not static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Problem is however, the Fieldpath in each Document is different so I cant query with a static Fieldpath.

If you don't know the full path of a field value to query, you simply can't query it.  There are no wildcards for document fields in a query.  It sounds like you will have to change your document structure if you want to perform the query, or at least just duplicate some data into another field that lets you make the query you want.  Duplicating data to satisfy queries is common in NoSQL type databases.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but  I dont think changing the Structure would work as this App is in production for at least 6 months now :/ But I will think about Duplicating Data, but dont really know how to implement it yet.

Comment: Then you're pretty much stuck.  You're going to have to define what information you have to filter for the document, and make that information available in a filterable field.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Fast replies I will definitely think of something!